# how to make unit tests work with jax-ws?

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, junit, glassfish, jax-ws

I have a webservice created with jax-ws 2.2 and my objective is to make the test connect to glassfish and behave like a real client but I'm getting this exception :

```
tried to access method com.sun.xml.ws.policy.PolicyMapMutator.connect(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/policy/PolicyMap;)V from class com.sun.xml.ws.policy.parser.WsitPolicyResolver
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.xml.ws.policy.PolicyMapMutator.connect(Lcom/sun/xml/ws/policy/PolicyMap;)V from class com.sun.xml.ws.policy.parser.WsitPolicyResolver
```

I'm using junit 4/jax-ws 2.2 and glassfish 3.1.1

Thanks.